# Translate pseudo code to assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, i386

I'm trying to translate some *C* pseudo code to i386 assembly code but never get it right.

```
n=1;
s=50;
a=0;  
while(n > 0) {
   a=s/n;
   n=n-1;
}
print a;
```

The code above is to be translated to assembly code through a compiler resulting in:

```
.data
variables: .space 104
msg: .asciz "Message %d\n"
.text
.global main
main:
    push    $1
    pop variables+52
    push    $50
    pop variables+72
    push    $0
    pop variables+0
L000:
    push    variables+52
    push    $0
    pop %ebx
    pop %eax
    cmp %ebx,%eax
    jl  L001
    push    variables+72
    push    variables+52
    pop %ebx
    pop %eax
    xor %edx,%edx
    idivl   %ebx
    push    %eax
    pop variables+0
    push    variables+52
    push    $1
    pop %ebx
    pop %eax
    sub %ebx,%eax
    push    %eax
    pop variables+52
    jmp L000
L001:
    push    variables+0
    push    $msg
    call    printf
    add $8,%esp
leave
ret
```

I can't get the code to run correctly. It results in a segmentation fault. The output I get is:

```
Message 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: You are aware there is a [mov instruction](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_176.html) that allows you to move values to and from memory into registers. You use a less efficient method of pushing things on the stack and popping them into their destination.

Comment: This simplifies to `a = s/1` (i.e. just s) if `n` is initially > 0, otherwise leave `a` unmodified.  There's no need to actually make a loop in asm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is a "division by zero". `jl  L001` leaves the loop if (n<0), but it should leave if (n<=0). So change it to `jle  L001` (jle = jump if less or equal).

Also, `leave` is wrong. There is no prolog that needs to be reversed. Remove it.

Comment: Thank you. I have been working on this compiler for little over three days now and my head is starting to go a bit messy.

Comment: @seb : I'd recommend compiling with the _GCC_ `-g3` option to add debug information. Then use GNU Debugger (gdb) to single step through your code. It is much easier to see how your code is going wrong and what lead to the error.